# Really Custom Reporting in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, metrics

I have a client who is currently using WebTrends for their analytics, and is considering making a move to Google Analytics.

However, from what I can tell, there is very little custom reporting available in GA.  For example, if a user was logged into the system, and I wanted to be able to do reporting on people with blue eyes, brown hair, etc., is this possible?

It looks like you can set one "god variable" with the pagetracker._setVar() JS method, but it is limited to one metric.  Any way to be able to track multiple metrics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull the data as XML from the Google Analytics API and produce your own reports.
Or you could set up 'campaign tracking' which allows you to append additional data to a URL which will then show up in the reports.